# How to install monitorx?

Tags: deb

I followed a tutorial at [unixmen](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-monitorix-in-ubuntu-fedora-and-centos/) on how to install [monitorx](http://www.monitorix.org/) in ubuntu
i installed the dependencies and downloaded the [monitorix_2.5.0-izzy1_all.deb](http://www.monitorix.org/monitorix_2.5.0-izzy1_all.deb) 
deb package but when i try to install it i get this error

google transtaler (i have a dutch Ubuntu and so was the error message)

```
dpkg: error processing monitorix_2.5.0-izzy1_all.deb (- install):
  parsing file '/ var / lib / dpkg / tmp.ci / control' near line 14 package 'monitorix':
  blank line in the value of field 'Description'
Errors were encountered while processing:
  monitorix_2.5.0-izzy1_all.deb
```

my question is how to get monitorx up and running in Ubuntu 11.10 amd64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, so I wrote the packager.  His new deb file worked for me, but I also had to install dependencies:

Edit: For the deb file, please email Andreas Itzchak Rehberg, you will find his email address on this page -- http://www.monitorix.org/downloads.html

**Installation**

```
cd ./Downloads
sudo dpkg -i monitorix_2.5.0-izzy2_all.deb
```

Comment: the link is bad your link is (http://%20http//www.izzysoft.de/ftp/monitorix_2.5.0-izzy2_all.deb) and it should be   "http://www.izzysoft.de/ftp/monitorix_2.5.0-izzy2_all.deb" but i still couldn't download the file. i get a 404 error file not found error

Comment: in downloaded the same file what is in my question (http://www.monitorix.org/monitorix_2.5.0-izzy1_all.deb) open it whit Ubuntu software center and got a bad package error i installed anyways and no further errors :)?

Comment: To save you the hazzle of manually downloading and solving the dependencies, you could also use the repository at http://apt.izzysoft.de/ with your `sources.list` – and the side-effect of receiving updates automatically. // Disclosure: I'm the above mentioned packager and the repository owner/maintainer. I work together closely with Jordi (dev of Monitorix) on this package, so updates are usually coming in-time.